# Is there a more efficient or generally better way to determine if a number is an integer than this?

Tags: javascript, integer

Right now I'm using this function to determine if a number is an integer:

```
function isInteger(input){
    return (input%1==0);
}
```

is there a more efficient way to do this? I know there's a built in javascript function for this but it doesn't work in certain IE versions.

Comment: Here a more efficient way to do it: [link](https://jsperf.com/numbers-and-integers)

Comment: maybe you want to use `return typeof input === 'number'` ,it is supported by IE [check MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

Comment: @VitaliiStrimbanu a number is not necessarily an integer, for example, look at `3.14`.

Comment: @vlaz thanks for pointing out this, my bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [jsPerf](https://jsperf.com/isinteger-once-more), `~~` ([repeated bitwise NOT](http://james.padolsey.com/cool-stuff/double-bitwise-not/)) and `<< 0` (shift left by 0 bits) are faster in my browser:

```
function isInteger(input) {
  return (~~input === input);
}

function isInteger2(input) {
  return (input << 0 === input);
}
```

> **WARNING**: JavaScript bitwise operators coerce their operands to [signed 32-bit integers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Signed_32-bit_integers), so this method is only safe for numbers up to `Math.pow(2, 31) -1` (2147483647). Use another method if you can't guarantee that.

Of the other methods, `n % 1 === 0` and `Math.floor(value) === value` are 40-50% slower and `Number.isInteger` is way behind.

However, they are all "pretty fast". Unless you have to check a **lot** of numbers, none of these methods are likely to be a bottleneck in your application.

Comment: BITWISE `NOT` IS DANGEROUS! Bitwise number arithmetic treats any number as 32bit, so with large numbers, you will get an overflow `~~10000000000// 1410065408`

Answer (score 1):

```
function isInteger(input){
    Number.isInteger(input)
}

Number.isInteger = Number.isInteger || function(value) {
  return typeof value === "number" && 
    isFinite(value) && 
    Math.floor(value) === value;
};
```

source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger#Polyfill

Answer (score -2):

```
function isInt(val) {
    return val + 0 === val;
}
```

Comment: But `1.5 + 0 === 1.5`